# Disable dropdown arrow in a TButton

Tags: delphi, button, drop-down-menu

In Delphi(XE5), you can set the style property to "bsSplitButton" to create a split button, add a dropdown arrow and assign a popup menu(DropDownMenu) to it, 
but how can i disable the the drop down arrow without disabling the whole button?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it more appropriate to disable the items in the dropdown menu?

Comment: well i want the user to not be able to press on the arrow until another thing is done, and the menu list might be affected ..

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you're asking at all. I think you'd have to handle it yourself in the button's `OnDropDownClick` event.

Comment: i want to it appear disabled too .. grayed ..

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot disable only the arrow, this kind of button ([BS_SPLITBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is handled by the WinAPI, and I don't see any reference in the MSDN documentation to disable that part of the button.

Comment: Make the button a normal button if you don't want a dropdown. But your ui seems weak.

Comment: If you describe what you're trying to do, perhaps we can offer a more standard, more intuitive suggestion for the UI.

Comment: PopupMenu and DropDownMenu are different things. AFAIR You can have PopUp Menu without DropDown one